# How I can force nginx to save response in a cache folder, with headers from upstream server?

Tags: django, caching, nginx

I use Django REST Framework for my API, nginx as a reverse proxy and redis for caching some static api data.
I was trying to implement caching with `Cache-Control: max-age` and `Last-Modify` headers.
In a nutshell it looks like this:

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ....
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        cache_key = self._get_cache_key() # get a key for reddis
        response = self._get_data_from_cache(cache_key) # get a data from reddis
        if response:
            # If data in redis return Response with a same Last-Modify
            # and 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=120'
            return response

        # Setting up new value for this viewset in a reddis
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        cache.set(cache_key, [now, serializer.data])
        return Response(serializer.data, headers={'Last-Modified': now, 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=120'})
```

It work like I expect, browser caching data for 120 seconds and when it expire client check content with an `If-Modified-Since` header.
But I though when I setting up `max-age` headers nginx will save it in a cache folder and will serving up all clients without hitting a server.
here is my testing nginx config from local machine:

```
upstream django {
  server 127.0.0.1:8002; 
}

proxy_cache_path /home/ivan/projects/kors/test_prod/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1; #
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

location /media  {
    alias /path/to/media; 
    expires 1y;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
location /static {
    alias /path/to/static; 
    expires 1y;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /path/to/uwsgi_params; 
    uwsgi_param Host $host;
    uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;

    proxy_cache my_cache;
    }
}
```

Consider this article [nginx-caching-guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/).

> How Does NGINX Determine Whether or Not to Cache Something?
>   By default, NGINX respects the Cache‑Control headers from origin servers. It does not cache responses with Cache‑Control set to Private, No‑Cache, or No‑Store or with Set‑Cookie in the response header. NGINX only caches GET and HEAD client requests. You can override these defaults as described in the answers below.

I thought a `Cache-Contol: max-age` header will force nginx to save json in a caching folder.
Folder was created but there is no data here and all my requests from separate browsers are hitting a server.
What am I missed? Or maybe I was totally misunderstood a concept of caching with nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of call you adding a `Cache-Control: max-age` in the header doesn't tell nginx to do anything with it. The client manages what to do with the header and how to process subsequent requests.

What your are probably is nginx response caching for a url. Don't see a issue with your nginx config as such.

```
uwsgi_cache_path /home/ivan/projects/kors/test_prod/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

location / {

    include     /path/to/uwsgi_params; 
    uwsgi_param Host $host;
    uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;

    uwsgi_cache my_cache;
    uwsgi_pass  django;
}
```

And you need to use uwsgi cache module here since.

See here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html

Comment: Thanks! cache saves now, but what the point of that cache if all new clients hits an upstream server anyway? Sorry If I'm totally misunderstanding a concept. What I thought will be `New client come -> hit a server -> nginx saves cache for 120 sec -> client get a response`, then in a 120 sec all new clients which call that resource get it from an nginx cache. I thought `reverse proxy` mean exactly what I described above.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. Are you not seeing the same.

Comment: no, I printed out code in my view for sure that server is hitting. When I serve first request in Chrome, server hits, then next requests in a Chrome does not hit a server. But when I send request from a Firefox while `max-age` does not expire, server get hit again.

Comment: Can you look into wsgi ignore headers http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_ignore_headers

Comment: `uwsgi_ignore_headers "Vary";` seems make it work correctly, thanks a lot. But I didn't get one, "First of call you adding a Cache-Control: max-age in the header doesn't tell nginx to do anything with it". Without that header provided nginx will not save data from that resource in a cache.